# Permission bigquery.tables.updateData denied when querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, service-accounts

I'm querying bigquery (via databricks) with a service account with the following roles:

```
BigQuery Data Viewer
BigQuery Job User
BigQuery Metadata Viewer
BigQuery Read Session User
```

The query is:

```
SELECT distinct(column_name) FROM `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` where data_type = "TIMESTAMP" and is_partitioning_column = "YES"
```

I'm actually querying via Azure Databricks:

```
  spark.read.format("bigquery")
  .option("materializationDataset", dataset)
  .option("parentProject", projectId)
  .option("query", query)
  .load()
  .collect()
```

But I'm getting:

```
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access Denied: Table project:dataset._sbc_f67ac00fbd5f453b90....: Permission bigquery.tables.updateData denied on table project:dataset._sbc_f67ac00fbd5f453b90.... (or it may not exist).",
    "reason" : "accessDenied"
  } ],
```

After adding `BigQuery Data Editor` the query works.
Why I need write permissions to view this metadata? Any lower permissions I can give?

In the docs I see that [only data viewer is required](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In the first part of your question, you share the granted role. But on which resource are granted this role? On the table or on the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery saves all query results to a temporary table if a specific table name is not specified.

From the [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#required_permissions), following permissions are required.

> - `bigquery.tables.create` permissions to create a new table
> - `bigquery.tables.updateData` to write data to a new table, overwrite a    table, or append data to a table
> - `bigquery.jobs.create` to run a query job

Since the service account already have `BigQuery Job User` role, it is able to run the query, it needs `BigQuery Data Editor` role for `bigquery.tables.create` and `bigquery.tables.updateData` permissions.

Comment: How can I run the query without saving the results? I just want to get the results without write permissions.

Comment: @sheldonzy It is not possible. Either you have to mention Destination table where BQ can save result else the result will be stored in temporary table. See the beginning of the document link I have shared. Whatever the BQ returns the query result, it returns from that table only.